# Java letter replacement in file

Tags: java, file

So I done this so far, my program works for example turning numbers `123`... into letters like `abc`...

But my problem is I can't make it work with special characters like : `č, ć, đ`. Problem is when I run it with special characters my **file** just **get deleted**.

**edit**: forgot to mention im working with `.srt` files , adding utf-8 in scanner worked for txt files, but when i tryed with `.srt` it just delete full contect from file.

The code:

```
LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>();

// Opening the file
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.srt"), "UTF-8");
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    lines.add(replaceLetters(line));
}
input.close();

// Saving the new edited version file
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("input.srt", "UTF-8");
for (String line: lines) {
    writer.println(line);
}
writer.close();
```

The replace method:

```
public static String replaceLetters(String orig) {
    String fixed = "";
    // Go through each letter and replace with new letter
    for (int i = 0; i < orig.length(); i++) {
        // Get the letter
        String chr = orig.substring(i, i + 1);
        // Replace letter if nessesary
        if (chr.equals("a")) {
            chr = "1";
        } else if (chr.equals("b")) {
            chr = "2";
        } else if (chr.equals("c")) {
            chr = "3";
        }

        // Add the new letter to the end of fixed
        fixed += chr;
    }
    return fixed;
}
```

Comment: Please explain more in detail what you are trying to achieve. Also give some examples.

Comment: Note that nowadays you should use Javas new I/O library called **NIO** to read and write files. It revolves around `Paths`, `Files` and `Path`.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
```

into

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

You save in `UTF-8`, but read in a default charset.

Also, next time, use `try-catch` statements properly and include them in your post.

Comment: To extend the answer: With **NIO** you don't have such problems anymore. It always uses **UTF-8** by default if not specifying something else. `Files.write(...)` and `Files.lines(...)` for example.